# Python, how to avoid the loop using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, loops

So I have two matrix, `W` and `X`.

```
print(W)
array([ 5.76951515, 19.        ])

print(X)
array([[ 1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  9.],
       [ 1., 10.],
       [ 1., 11.],
       [ 1., 12.],
       [ 1., 13.],
       [ 1., 14.]])
```

and I'd like multiply both matrix `W` and `X`, varying the value of `W[1]` for each `i` iterations, like this.

```
for i in range(10):
  W[1] = i
  yP_ = W @ X.T
  ecm = np.mean((Y - yP_ ) ** 2)
  plt.plot(W[1], ecm, 'o')
plt.show()
```

is there any way to avoid that `for`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the `for`? Performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making `W` shape `(10,2)`, and keeping the range `0-9` in the second column. Then the rows of the product `W @ X.T` are the iterations of your current for-loop.

```py
W2 = np.full((10,2), W[0])
W2[:,1] = np.arange(10)
W2
# array([[5.76951515, 0.        ],
#        [5.76951515, 1.        ],
#          ...
#        [5.76951515, 9.        ]])
```

So you can do

```py
ecm = np.mean((Y - W2 @ X.T)**2, axis=1)  # average across columns
plt.plot(W2[:,1], ecm, 'o')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by generating the modified `W` array, and then apply the matrix product just as you where:

```
N=10
W_ = np.c_[[W[0]]*N, np.arange(N)]
yP_ = W_@X.T
```

---

Quick check:

```
yP_ = []
for i in range(N):
    W[1] = i
    yP_.append(W @ X.T)

np.allclose(np.array(yP_), W_@X.T)
# True
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I think your answer is more efficient than the other guy's because he's filling the array and then updates the column, however both of you helped me. If you agree, I will accept his answer, according to SO he replied faster, and he has many fewer points in his account than you have. Also, I think it could motivate him to keep answering questions. Anyway, tell me if that's okay with you.

Comment: It's entirely up to you @Sharki But that is maybe overthinking it a little bit :) Generally you should keep in mind what future visitors will benefit of the most, though this question is quite specific, so it doesn't matter as much in this case.

Comment: You're right, it just feels a little unfair since both of you helped me so I can't promote both of you, however, thanks! :)